# @SpringQueryMapper Unable to get parent class attribute

Tags: spring-cloud-feign, feign

I am using the spring-cloud-feign Greenwich.RELEASE version.

example 1:

```
public class PageParameter {

  private int pageSize = 10;

  private int pageNumber = 1;

  public int getPageSize() {
    return pageSize;
  }

  public void setPageSize(int pageSize) {
    this.pageSize = pageSize;
  }

  public int getPageNumber() {
    return pageNumber;
  }

  public void setPageNumber(int pageNumber) {
    this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
  }
}

public class QueryModel extends PageParameter {

}

public interface QueryFeign {

  @GetMapping("/query")
  String get(@SpringQueryMap QueryModel query);
}
```

expected:[QueryFeign#get] ---> GET http://xxxxxx/query?pageNumber=1&pageSize=10 HTTP/1.1
actual:[QueryFeign#get] ---> GET http://xxxxxx/query HTTP/1.1

example 2:

```
public class PageParameter {

  private int pageSize = 10;

  private int pageNumber = 1;

  public int getPageSize() {
    return pageSize;
  }

  public void setPageSize(int pageSize) {
    this.pageSize = pageSize;
  }

  public int getPageNumber() {
    return pageNumber;
  }

  public void setPageNumber(int pageNumber) {
    this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
  }
}

public interface QueryFeign {

  @GetMapping("/query")
  String get(@SpringQueryMap PageParameter query);
}
```

expected:[QueryFeign#get] ---> GET http://xxxxxx/query?pageNumber=1&pageSize=10 HTTP/1.1
actual:[QueryFeign#get] ---> GET http://xxxxxx/query?pageNumber=1&pageSize=10 HTTP/1.1

why inherited properties make @SpringQueryMap not work

Comment: Experiencing the same issue, looks like a bug

Comment: filed an issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/168

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/141